# Unable to animate transform: scale and box-shadow simultaneously

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms, box-shadow

I need to animate the circle's `box-shadow` and scale it down to 1 from 1.6x during the same transition period of `box-shadow`.

The issue I'm facing is the animation of scale is happening after the animation of `box-shadow` is done.

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

.ripple {
  width: 20px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: rippleeff 2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes rippleeff {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
    transform: scale(1.4);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    transform: scale(1.6);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ripple">

</div>
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/f6223vkp/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `transform: scale(1.6)`, your box-shadow become `transparent` and after that when you going to `scale(1)` your `box-shadow` is animating but you can't see it because it's transparent...so change `box-shadow` color

Also changed scale value in the code...

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

.ripple {
  width: 20px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: rippleeff 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rippleeff {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    transform: scale(1.6);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ripple">

</div>
```

Comment: That worked. I didn't see the change in value of `a` in `rgba`. Thanks